# SQL SERVER 2008 SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a question regarding to SSIS.  I designed a package and it worked fine when I executed in my local machine.  I used to extract the data from Teradata and load into SQL SERVER 2008. Everything was fine but I'm looking for how to execute the package without my local machine.  I mean how to configure and set up the odbc in the SSIS server machine, not my local machine.

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: Could you help clarify precisely what your question is about? You've built a package to extract data using a Teradata provider. You need to migrate this package to a server. Go

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you've [installed SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731(v=sql.100).aspx) on the box; then there's a number of ways to go about running it.  From there, I prefer to connect to Integration Services from the Object Explorer in SSMS and import packages, using the "SQL Server" as the Package Location.  Once the Integration Services on the box has an entry for the package, you'll be able to run it with the agent by specifying a step type of "SQL Server Integration Services Package."  I don't think you will need to set up the ODBC on the server itself if you have it configured correctly in your package, but if you do that should be no different than the way you have it set up on your own box.

[image: Object Explorer]

Comment: I think they're looking for "how do I set up a terradata ODBC connection". Not how to run it. Am I misreading?

Comment: Reading it again, I am still taking away "Would like to run this on a server instead of my workstation" - you could be right though, my SO speak is rudimentary.  See what they says when they get back, go from there!

Comment: Yes, I would like everyone could run my package in SSIS. I imported my package and stored it in SSIS however, my teammate couldn't run my package. I checked the log file, it looks like can't connect Teradata because the id and password fail to connect. but when I re-run the package in my machine, it worked well.

Regards,

Paul

Comment: Right, then you should log into the server and set up the ODBC connection as you have it on your local machine, making sure you have the correct drivers and such.  If you can get the package running from the server itself, it should run for anybody who can execute it.  Are you using an ADO.NET connection for the Teradata source?  Just curious, I hear the ADO.NET style connections are less finicky for Teradata.

Comment: Pass-through authentication on your connection object in your package?  Through AD or something, maybe?

Comment: I tried to set Pass-through authentication but looks like it doesn't.  I use other computer to run the package but it didn't work. it has some connection issue. my computer has no issue, worked good.

Comment: Can you connect to the Teradata server from the MS SQL 2008 server?  It might be behind a firewall or something.  Get the error message you receive when you try to run the package from the new host box and update your question, I might be able to help from there.  Additionally, with pass-through, it may be that your coworkers permissions on the Teradata server are not as encompassing as your own.

Comment: I could connect Teradata from my local computer. In package, I used ADO.net and there is no issue at all. I could run the package in SSIS from my local computer without any error. Only running in other computer has errors.

Comment: Here is the error:  ERROR: Microsoft.SQLServer.Dts.Runtime.DstCouldNotCreateManagedConectionException: Could not create a managed connectition manager. At Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedConnection(String AssamblyQuanlifyName.String connStr.Object transaction.

Comment: That error is not a normal permissions error - that's going to be on account of the driver you are using for the connection in the SSIS package not being available on the SQL Server 2008 box.  Install the driver you use to connect to Teradata through SSIS on your local machine on your server as well; you should at least get a different error then.